# How to set and get using class in perl?

Tags: perl

Im trying to set and get the values in the perl using classes.

below is my parent class `math.pm`.

```
use strict;
package math;

sub new
{
        my $class=shift;
        my $self={};
        bless($self,$class);
        return $self;
}

sub set_number
{
        my $self=shift;
        my $self->{'num'}=shift;
}

sub get_number
{
        my $self=shift;
        return $self->{'num'};
}

sub add
{
        my $self=shift;
        my $num1=shift;
        my $num2=shift;
        return $num1 + $num2;
}

sub multiply
{
        my $self=shift;
        my $num1=shift;
        my $num2=shift;
        return $num1 * $num2 ;
}

1;
```

below is the script from where im calling the parent class `math` in a derived class called `operations`

```
use strict;
use math;

package operations;
our @ISA = qw/math/;

my $number_obj1=operations->new();
my $number_obj2=operations->new();
my $number_obj3=operations->new();

$number_obj1->set_number("23");
$number_obj2->set_number("24");

my $num1=print $number_obj1->get_number();
my $num2=print $number_obj2->get_number();

print "\n\$num1:$num1\n\$num2:$num2\n";

print "addition: ",$number_obj3->add("$num1","$num2"),"\n";
print "multiplication: ",$number_obj3->multiply("$num1","$num2"),"\n";
```

improper output:

```
$num1:1
$num2:1
addition: 2
multiplication: 1
```

in above script i'm not able to fetch values into `$num1` and `$num2` using `get_number` sub routine.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Please note that by convention, package names in Perl should start with a capital letter. The correct name for your class would be `Math`, not `math`. All lower-case names are reserved for _pragmas_ like `strict`.

Comment: I would suggest for you to post this code on [codereview.se]. There are some stylistic issues as well as a bit of Perl general knowledge you seem to lack. I believe you would greatly benefit from a proper code review.

Comment: Note that `operations` is a simple program, not a derived class at all (it has no methods, not even a constructor). You should omit the `package` statement and the assignment to `@ISA`.

Comment: Also note that the methods `math::add` and `math::multiply` are unaffected by the state of the object. They do exactly the same as the `+` and `*` operators, but using a lot of code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on `warnings` and it'll tell you:

```
"my" variable $self masks earlier declaration in same scope at line 17.
```

You need to change:

```
sub set_number {
   my $self = shift;
   my $self->{'num'} = shift;
}
```

That second `my` is what's breaking it, because it's creating a new instance of `$self`.

Also: `my $num = print ..`

Is almost certainly not doing what you want it to - it's setting `$num` to the return code of `print`.

Try instead:

```
my $num1 =  $number_obj1->get_number();
my $num2 =  $number_obj2->get_number();
```

Output:

```
$num1:23
$num2:24
addition: 47
multiplication: 552
```

Comment: That's not all. I also spotted that, but once it's fixed, it will still produce only `1` as values. There has to be a list context issue somewhere.... it's the `print`.

Comment: Yeah. Assigning the result of `print` by the looks.